# Proof of equivalent definitions of strictly convex norms

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space. We want to show that these two definitions of a strictly convex norm are equivalent: for any $x$ and $y$ in $X$ such that $x\neq y$ and $\lVert x\rVert=\lVert y\rVert=1$

> $(1): \quad \lVert x+y\rVert <2 \\
>    (2): \quad \lVert \alpha x+(1-\alpha)y\rVert <1\quad\text{for all }0<\alpha<1$

Clearly, $(2)$ implies $(1)$ by selecting $\alpha=1/2$. How do we show that $(1)$ implies $(2)$?

Answer (score 0):

We begin by noting that
$$\begin{split} \lVert \alpha x+(1-\alpha)y\rVert &=\lVert \alpha x+\alpha y+(1-2\alpha)y\rVert \\& 
< 2\alpha + |1-2\alpha| \\&
=1\quad\text{when } \alpha \leq 1/2.\end{split}$$

When $1/2<\alpha<1$, we use the fact that $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y=\beta y+(1-\beta)x$, where $\beta=1-\alpha<1/2$. Thus, the above argument applies w.r.t. $\beta$ (and interchange $x$ and $y$).